# Rails - Wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Properties model which is using a field to sort by property type(properties.kind).

```
class Property < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :house, -> { where(kind: "House") }
  scope :apartment, -> { where(kind: "Apartment") }
  scope :commercial, -> { where(kind: "Commercial") }
end
```

Then in my Properties controller I'm combining them into an array so that I can group them by type in the view.

```
class PropertiesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @house = Property.house.all
    @apartment = Property.apartment.all
    @commercial = Property.commercial.all

    @listing = [@house, @apartment, @commercial]
  end
```

The problem that stands out to me is that the model must perform at least 3 SQL queries on the same table for every index action.  Obviously this is super inefficient, and ill be lucky if I can serve more than one user at a time.

My question is this: is there a better way to group an array's contents by a string value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine these into a single query and keep them scoped as follows:

```
scope :listing, -> { where(kind: ["House","Apartment","Commercial"]) }
```

Passing an array to Where is an alias in SQL for IN, which will cover all 3 options in one query. You could then split them out with a `group_by` for assigning them to instance variables.